# Postgresql - How to get record from the same table that doesn't occur specific data

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL, if i have this kind of record :

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Name           |     Paid         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Teddy        |        No        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Andy         |        No        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Andy         |        Yes       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Sarah        |        Yes       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Michael      |        No        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Michael      |        Yes       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

How do i get Names that don't have 'Yes' occurence in the table?

In this example the result should be : Teddy.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `not exists` with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.name, t.paid
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.name = t.name and t1.paid = 'Yes'
)
```

For performance with this query, you want an index on `(name, paid)`.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select name
from table
where name not in (
    select name 
    from table 
    where paid = 'Yes'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values are only `'Yes'` and `'No'`:

```
select name
from t
group by name
having min(paid) = max(paid) and min(paid) = 'No';
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
select name 
from yourtable
group by name
having count (*) filter (where paid = 'Yes') = 0
```

This will do at most a single scan of the table, which may be helpful if your table is large.